# Cannot export to .txt whilst it's being used (vb)

Tags: vb.net

[image]

I am trying to outside text to a log file for my application. But every time it tries I get the error shown in the image :/

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Dim exporter As New StreamWriter("C:\log.txt")
exporter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\log.txt", True)

exporter.WriteLine(log)
exporter.Close()
```

Comment: You first create a `StreamWriter` around the file, then you try to `OpenTextFileWriter`. That would be two writers to the same file. Also, do you actually debug your application by running the exe outside of the VS?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that (This code will replace de entire file. if you want to append, you'll need to read de actual value and then write or just use the append function):

```
       Using exporter = New StreamWriter("C:\log.txt")
            exporter.WriteLine(log)
        End Using
```

The issue happens because you are using the file two times. The first one when you put New StreamWriter, e the second one when you OpenTextFileWriter before close the first one.

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: Good to Know!!!! Can u mark this as the correct answer, please?! (If it was the case)

Comment: @RMH : The `StreamWriter` has the possibility to append as well (without having to read te entire file) [**if you use the correct overload**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx): `New StreamWriter("C:\log.txt", True)`.

Comment: Yes.., but I didn't know what you want to do (because of that I said "or just use the append function"). Good to know that it is workig!!! Good job!

Comment: I'm not the OP... Always make sure to check the name of a comment's author.